# Factorial Algorithms in different languages

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I want to see all the different ways you can come up with, for a factorial subroutine, or program. The hope is that anyone can come here and see if they might want to learn a new language.

### Ideas:

- Procedural
- Functional
- Object Oriented
- One liners
- Obfuscated
- Oddball
- Bad Code
- [Polyglot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29)

Basically I want to see an example, of different ways of writing an algorithm, and what they would look like in different languages.

Please limit it to one example per entry.
I will allow you to have more than one example per answer, if you are trying to highlight a specific style, language, or just a well thought out idea that lends itself to being in one post.

The only real requirement is it must find the factorial of a given argument, in all languages represented.

## Be Creative!

### Recommended Guideline:

```
# Language Name: Optional Style type

   - Optional bullet points

    Code Goes Here

Other informational text goes here
```

I will ocasionally go along and edit any answer that does not have decent formatting.

Comment: Everybody who does factorials using recursion is in a state of sin! Only recursive Fibonacci is worse. :-)

Answer (score 184, accepted):

## Polyglot: 5 languages, all using bignums

So, I wrote a polyglot which works in the three languages I often write in, as well as one from my other answer to this question and one I just learned today.  It's a standalone program, which reads a single line containing a nonnegative integer and prints a single line containing its factorial.  Bignums are used in all languages, so the maximum computable factorial depends only on your computer's resources.

- **Perl**: uses built-in bignum package.  Run with `perl FILENAME`.
- **Haskell**: uses built-in bignums.  Run with `runhugs FILENAME` or your favorite compiler's equivalent.
- **C++**: requires GMP for bignum support.  To compile with g++, use `g++ -lgmpxx -lgmp -x c++ FILENAME` to link against the right libraries.  After compiling, run `./a.out`.  Or use your favorite compiler's equivalent.
- **brainf*ck**: I wrote some bignum support in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930/factorial-algorithms-in-different-languages/432010#432010).  Using [Muller's classic distribution](http://aminet.net/package.php?package=dev/lang/brainfuck-2.lha), compile with `bf < FILENAME > EXECUTABLE`.  Make the output executable and run it.  Or use your favorite distribution.
- **Whitespace**: uses built-in bignum support.  Run with `wspace FILENAME`.

*Edit:* added Whitespace as a fifth language.  Incidentally, do *not* wrap the code with `<code>` tags; it breaks the Whitespace.  Also, the code looks much nicer in fixed-width.

```
char //# b=0+0{- |0*/; #>>>>,----------[>>>>,--------
#define	a/*#--]>>>>++<<<<<<<<[>++++++[<------>-]<-<<<
#Perl	><><><>	 <> <> <<]>>>>[[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>-]<->
#C++	--><><>	<><><><	> < > <	+<[>>>>+<<<-<[-]]>[-]
#Haskell >>]>[-<<<<<[<<<<]>>>>[[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>-]>>]
#Whitespace	>>>>[-[>+<-]+>>>>]<<<<[<<<<]<<<<[<<<<
#brainf*ck > < ]>>>>>[>>>[>>>>]>>>>[>>>>]<<<<[[>>>>*/
exp; ;//;#+<<<<-]<<<<]>>>>+<<<<<<<[<<<<][.POLYGLOT^5.
#include <gmpxx.h>//]>>>>-[>>>[>>>>]>>>>[>>>>]<<<<[>>
#define	eval int	main()//>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>+>->
#include <iostream>//<]<-[>>+<<[-]]<<[<<<<]>>>>[>[>>>
#define	print std::cout	<< // >	<+<-]>[<<+>+>-]<<[>>>
#define	z std::cin>>//<< +<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>+>-]<->+++++
#define c/*++++[-<[-[>>>>+<<<<-]]>>>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<<*/
#define	abs int $n //><	<]<[>>+<<<<[-]>>[<<+>>-]]>>]<
#define	uc mpz_class fact(int	$n){/*<<<[<<<<]<<<[<<
use bignum;sub#<<]>>>>-]>>>>]>>>[>[-]>>>]<<<<[>>+<<-]
z{$_[0+0]=readline(*STDIN);}sub fact{my($n)=shift;#>>
#[<<+>+>-]<->+<[>-<[-]]>[-<<-<<<<[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>+*/
uc;if($n==0){return 1;}return $n*fact($n-1);	}//;#
eval{abs;z($n);print fact($n);print("\n")/*2;};#-]<->
'+<[>-<[-]]>]<<[<<<<]<<<<-[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>-]+<[>-+++
-}--	<[-]]>[-<<++++++++++<<<<-[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>-++
fact 0	= 1 -- ><><><><	> <><><	]+<[>-<[-]]>]<<[<<+ +
fact	n=n*fact(n-1){-<<]>>>>[[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+++>+-}
main=do{n<-readLn;print(fact n)}-- +>-]<->+<[>>>>+<<+
{-x<-<[-]]>[-]>>]>]>>>[>>>>]<<<<[>+++++++[<+++++++>-]
<--.<<<<]+written+by+++A+Rex+++2009+.';#+++x-}--x*/;}
```

Comment: The largest factorial computable in one second (not counting output) on my computer by the various languages in this implementation: C++ gets 45000!, Haskell gets 35000!, Whitespace gets 11000!, Perl gets 2000!, and brainf*ck gets 350!.

Comment: After staring at this code for a few minutes, my eyes kept drifting unexplicably to the `offensive?` link....

Comment: [steven@emu:~]% g++ -lgmpxx -lgmp -x c++ -I/opt/local/include -o test test.cpp
test.cpp:16:35: error: unterminated comment

gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)

:(

Comment: @Steven Schlansker: It's a bug in the Stack Overflow display code that I don't know how to get around.  (The code is being cut off above.)  If you look at the revision history, it'll display the code correctly.

Comment: Hopefully got the spacing right, but that should have fixed the truncation issue.

Comment: @e.c.ho: You fixed the truncation issue but broke the Whitespace code.  I've reverted back to my edit, which keeps the truncation issue fixed but makes the Whitespace work again.  Thanks for your help!  @Steven Schlansker: It should work now in all languages.

Answer (score 124):

### lolcode:

sorry I couldn't resist xD

```
HAI
CAN HAS STDIO?
I HAS A VAR
I HAS A INT
I HAS A CHEEZBURGER
I HAS A FACTORIALNUM
IM IN YR LOOP
    UP VAR!!1
    TIEMZD INT!![CHEEZBURGER]
    UP FACTORIALNUM!!1
    IZ VAR BIGGER THAN FACTORIALNUM? GTFO
IM OUTTA YR LOOP
U SEEZ INT
KTHXBYE
```

Comment: There's some problems here, like the fact that the loop will never gtfo. I pastebinned a better one http://pastebin.com/f7b2dd022

Answer (score 52):

This is one of the faster algorithms, up to [170!](http://www.google.com/search?q=170!).  It [fails](http://www.google.com/search?q=171!) inexplicably beyond 170!, and it's relatively slow for small factorials, but for factorials between [80](http://www.google.com/search?q=80!) and [170](http://www.google.com/search?q=170!) it's blazingly fast compared to many algorithms.

```
curl http://www.google.com/search?q=170!
```

There's also an online interface, [try it out now!](http://www.google.com/search?q=42!)

Let me know if you find a bug, or faster implementation for large factorials.

---

#### EDIT:

This algorithm is slightly slower, but gives results beyond 170:

```
curl http://www58.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=171!
```

It also simplifies them into various other representations.

Comment: Use MPFR (http://www.mpfr.org/). It allows floats with exponents in the 2^(2^32) range, or so...

Comment: I suspect that google's factorial algorithm has an limit to prevent inordinate amounts of processing time.  Were I them, I'd simply use a table - and it could be that they felt the table needn't be any larger than 170 entries.

Comment: That's a thing Wolfram Alpha performs better at than Google does :)

Comment: second one is pretty fast even:
http://www58.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999!

Comment: Chris S, surely not: Google can go beyond 170.
http://www.google.com/search?q=170.62437!

Comment: Google uses 1024bit numbers for internal representation. 171! is too big to fit in 1024 bits.

Comment: @Adam: Google is using double-precision floats and you're hitting their maximum value.

Comment: yay!!  
`170.6243769563027208124443787857704267195526247611752350848214460792185169909237066410499619266308320574638750507720015864509844270281483286810591859944048382387248073012794174415578250989772916148232661861809004627715858001037512378786340697749539591336332530617682681!`

Answer (score 48):

## C++: Template Metaprogramming

Uses the classic enum hack.

```
template<unsigned int n>
struct factorial {
    enum { result = n * factorial<n - 1>::result };
};

template<>
struct factorial<0> {
    enum { result = 1 };
};
```

Usage.

```
const unsigned int x = factorial<4>::result;
```

Factorial is calculated completely at compile time based on the template parameter n. Therefore, factorial<4>::result is a constant once the compiler has done its work.

Comment: The enum isn't needed if you just declare the result as a "static const int" field.  I.e. "static const int result = n * factorial<n - 1>::result;".

The "enum hack" is only needed for Visual Studio 6 C++ compiler, which didn't support templates properly.

Comment: A caveat with this solution is that, the ANSI C++ standard only enforces compilers to execute this kind of compile-time functions up to a limit - I believe 20 - of recursion levels. After that, you're in uncharted territory, left to the mercy of compiler creators.

Comment: I think factorial<20> is the largest factorial that can be represented by a signed 64-bit long, so that works out okay

Comment: @Kip is correct, 20! is less than 2^64, but 21! is larger than 2^64.

Comment: pauldoo, but then you also have to define that static const integer. not doing so may end up in a compile error for some compiler (the standard allows compilers not to diagnose that violation - thus you often don't see it rejected)

Comment: litb: I thought the standard allowed const int's to be defined in the header only?

Comment: The painful thing is that calculating the factorial at compile time is probably the right thing, for any factorial you want to calculate exactly, so the TMP nightmare will actually be the correct solution in real life, sort of...

Answer (score 34):

## Whitespace

```
   	.
 .
 	.
		.
  	.
   	.
			 .
 .
	 	 .
	  .
   	.
 .
  .
 			 .
		  			 .
 .
	.
.
  	 .
 .
.
	.
 	.
.
.
.
```

It was hard to get it to show here properly, but now I tried copying it from the preview and it works. You need to input the number and press enter.

Comment: Makes even advanced languages like Haskell look downright obvious.

Answer (score 34):

I find the following implementations just hilarious:

[The Evolution of a Haskell Programmer](http://www.willamette.edu/~fruehr/haskell/evolution.html)

[Evolution of a Python programmer](http://dis.4chan.org/read/prog/1180084983/)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 26):

C# Lookup:

Nothing to calculate really, just look it up. To extend it,add another 8 numbers to the table and 64 bit integers are at at their limit. Beyond that, a BigNum class is called for.

```
public static int Factorial(int f)
{ 
    if (f<0 || f>12)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Out of range for integer factorial");
    }
    int [] fact={1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880,3628800,
                 39916800,479001600};
    return fact[f];
}
```

Comment: Bravo.  Perhaps the fastest implementation here, and as valid as it could be with that type signature.

Comment: i think, many implementations can be faster for values from 0 to 12 because .NET can start slowly

Answer (score 26):

## [Lazy](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~tromp/cl/lazy-k.html) [K](http://esoteric.sange.fi/essie2/download/)

Your pure functional programming nightmares come true!

The only [Esoteric Turing-complete Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language) that has:

- A purely functional foundation, core, and libraries---in fact, here's the complete API: [S K I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus)
- No [lambdas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus) even!
- No [numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_numerals) or lists needed or allowed
- No explicit recursion but yet, [allows recursion](http://mvanier.livejournal.com/2897.html)
- A simple [infinite lazy stream](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/sicp/book/node71.html)-based I/O mechanism

Here's the Factorial code in all its parenthetical glory:

```
K(SII(S(K(S(S(KS)(S(K(S(KS)))(S(K(S(KK)))(S(K(S(K(S(K(S(K(S(SI(K(S(K(S(S(KS)K)I))
 (S(S(KS)K)(SII(S(S(KS)K)I))))))))K))))))(S(K(S(K(S(SI(K(S(K(S(SI(K(S(K(S(S(KS)K)I))
 (S(S(KS)K)(SII(S(S(KS)K)I))(S(S(KS)K))(S(SII)I(S(S(KS)K)I))))))))K)))))))
 (S(S(KS)K)(K(S(S(KS)K)))))))))(K(S(K(S(S(KS)K)))K))))(SII))II)
```

Features:

- No subtraction or conditionals
- Prints all factorials (if you wait long enough)
- Uses a second layer of Church numerals to convert the Nth factorial to N! asterisks followed by a newline
- Uses the [Y combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_point_combinator#Y_combinator) for recursion

In case you are interested in trying to understand it, here is the Scheme source code to run through the Lazier compiler:

```
(lazy-def '(fac input)
   '((Y (lambda (f n a) ((lambda (b) ((cons 10) ((b (cons 42)) (f (1+ n) b))))
       (* a n)))) 1 1))
```

(for suitable definitions of Y, cons, 1, 10, 42, 1+, and *).

EDIT:

## Lazy K Factorial in Decimal

([10KB of gibberish](http://www.updike.org/hazy/facdec.lazy) or else I would paste it). For example, at the Unix prompt:

```
    $ echo "4" | ./lazy facdec.lazy
    24
    $ echo "5" | ./lazy facdec.lazy
    120
```

Rather slow for numbers above, say, 5.

The code is sort of bloated because we have to include [library code for all of our own primitives](http://www.updike.org/hazy/factorialDecimal.hazy) (code written in [Hazy](http://www.updike.org/hazy/), a lambda calculus interpreter and LC-to-Lazy K compiler written in Haskell).

Answer (score 21):

### XSLT 1.0

The input file, **factorial.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="factorial.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<n>
  20
</n>
```

The XSLT file, **factorial.xsl**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"                     
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" >
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <!-- 0! = 1 -->
  <xsl:template match="text()[. = 0]">
    1
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- n! = (n-1)! * n-->
  <xsl:template match="text()[. > 0]">
    <xsl:variable name="x">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set( . - 1 )/text()"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$x * ."/>
  </xsl:template>
  <!-- Calculate n! -->
  <xsl:template match="/n">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Save both files in the same directory and open **factorial.xml** in IE.

Answer (score 19):

## Python: Functional, One-liner

```
factorial = lambda n: reduce(lambda x,y: x*y, range(1, n+1), 1)
```

NOTE:

- It supports big integers. Example:

---

```
print factorial(100)
93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915\
608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

---

- It does not work for *n < 0*.

Comment: operator.mul would be much faster than lambda x,y: x*y.

Comment: @spiv: `x*y` is 1.10-1.6 times slower then `mul`. math.factorial is faster then both. And memoized factorial is faster then math.factorial, etc. The question is not about performance.

Answer (score 18):

## [APL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)) (oddball/one-liner):

```
×/⍳X
```

1. ⍳X expands X into an array of the integers 1..X
2. ×/ multiplies every element in the array

Or with the built-in operator:

```
!X
```

Source: http://www.webber-labs.com/mpl/lectures/ppt-slides/01.ppt

Answer (score 15):

## Perl6

```
sub factorial ($n) { [*] 1..$n }
```

I hardly know about Perl6. But I guess this `[*]` operator is same as Haskell's `product`.

This code runs on [Pugs](http://pugscode.org/), and maybe [Parrot](http://www.parrot.org/) (I didn't check it.)

**Edit**

This code also works.

```
sub postfix:<!> ($n) { [*] 1..$n }

# This function(?) call like below ... It looks like mathematical notation.
say 10!;
```

Comment: This has got to be the shortest one I have seen.

Comment: Ok I guess there is one that is shorter, but who uses APL anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930/factorial-algorithms-in-different-languages#81669

Comment: multi postfix<!>($n){[*]1..$n}

Comment: Do you want to say `multi sub postfix:<!> ($n) { [*] 1..$n }`, Brad? It works on pugs. `10!` is evaluated as `3628800`. It's COOL! but pugs said `*** No such subroutine: "&COOL"`.

Comment: I just quickly posted a comment. The main point of the comment is TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: [*] 1..5 == 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5; [+] 1..5 = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5

Comment: Just don't try to learn Perl5 at the same time as trying to learn Perl6. Unless of course you want your head to explode.

Comment: Rakudo now supports the postfix:<!> variant http://perlgeek.de/blog-en/perl-6/custom-operators-in-rakudo.writeback

Answer (score 14):

## x86-64 Assembly: Procedural

You can call this from C (only tested with GCC on linux amd64).
Assembly was assembled with nasm.

```
section .text
    global factorial
; factorial in x86-64 - n is passed in via RDI register
; takes a 64-bit unsigned integer
; returns a 64-bit unsigned integer in RAX register
; C declaration in GCC:
;   extern unsigned long long factorial(unsigned long long n);
factorial:
    enter 0,0
    ; n is placed in rdi by caller
    mov rax, 1 ; factorial = 1
    mov rcx, 2 ; i = 2
loopstart:
    cmp rcx, rdi
    ja loopend
    mul rcx ; factorial *= i
    inc rcx
    jmp loopstart
loopend:
    leave
    ret
```

Answer (score 13):

### Recursively in Inform 7

(it reminds you of COBOL because it's for writing text adventures; proportional font is deliberate):

> To decide what number is the factorial of (n - a number):
>     if n is zero, decide on one;
>     otherwise decide on the factorial of (n minus one) times n.

If you want to actually call this function ("phrase") from a game you need to define an action and grammar rule:

> "The factorial game" [this must be the first line of the source]
>
> There is a room. [there has to be at least one!]
>
> Factorialing is an action applying to a number.
>
> Understand "factorial [a number]" as factorialing.
>
> Carry out factorialing:
>     Let n be the factorial of the number understood;
>     Say "It's [n]".

Answer (score 12):

Haskell:

```
ones = 1 : ones
integers   = head ones     : zipWith (+) integers   (tail ones)
factorials = head integers : zipWith (*) factorials (tail integers)
```

Comment: I think you are missing a parentheses, but the ( after the 3: is unnecessary.

Comment: Your factorial is [1, 2, 3, 6, 18, 108, ...] instead of true factorial [1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, ...].

Comment: `factorials = 1 : (scanl1 (*) . scanl1 (+) . repeat $ 1)`

Answer (score 12):

## C#: LINQ

```
    public static int factorial(int n)
    {
        return (Enumerable.Range(1, n).Aggregate(1, (previous, value) => previous * value));
    }
```

Comment: public static long factorial(int n){}

Comment: public static long factorial(byte n){}

Answer (score 12):

## Erlang: tail recursive

```
fac(0) -> 1;
fac(N) when N > 0 -> fac(N, 1).

fac(1, R) -> R;
fac(N, R) -> fac(N - 1, R * N).
```

Comment: One-liner for the sake of it:
> Fact = fun(N) when N > 0 -> lists:foldl(fun(X,Y)->X*Y end, 1, lists:seq(1,N)) end.

Answer (score 11):

## Brainf*ck

```
+++++
>+<[[->>>>+<<<<]>>>>[-<<<<+>>+>>]<<<<>[->>+<<]<>>>[-<[->>+<<]>>[-<<+<+>>>]<]<[-]><<<-]
```

Written by Michael Reitzenstein.

Comment: From http://www.blitzbasic.com/Community/posts.php?topic=36823.
The output is placed in memory slot #2.

Comment: Note: as a result, on the standard implementation, this can only compute up to 5!.  (Memory cells are usually one byte.)  See post #432010 for a solution.

Answer (score 10):

## BASIC: old school

```
10 HOME
20 INPUT N
30 LET ANS = 1
40 FOR I = 1 TO N
50   ANS = ANS * I
60 NEXT I
70 PRINT ANS
```

Answer (score 9):

## F#: Functional

#### Straight forward:

```
let rec fact x = 
    if   x < 0 then failwith "Invalid value."
    elif x = 0 then 1
    else x * fact (x - 1)
```

#### Getting fancy:

```
let fact x = [1 .. x] |> List.fold_left ( * ) 1
```

Comment: You can also get fancier with unfold: 
let factorial n =
    (1,1)
 |> Seq.unfold (fun (n,p) -> let p' = n*p in Some (p',(n+1,p')))
 |> Seq.nth (n-1)

Comment: @namim: or for something less overkill, "let fact x = [2 .. x] |> List.scan_left ( * ) 1"

Answer (score 9):

Batch (NT):

```
@echo off

set n=%1
set result=1

for /l %%i in (%n%, -1, 1) do (
    set /a result=result * %%i
)

echo %result%
```

Usage: 
C:>factorial.bat 15

Comment: Note that you need to have the registry patch to enable variable updates within loops!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what patch is that?  I certainly haven't ever modified my registry so I could do something like this.

Comment: Works on my computer (Windows XP SP3) without any patches.

Comment: @Jeff: See cmd /? and set /? for info about delayed variable expansion. If it's disabled by default, you need to either tweak the registry, launch cmd with the /v:on switch or just put put setlocal enabledelayedexpansion at the beginning of your batch file.

Comment: @JeffHillman: here's a [recursive version](https://gist.github.com/1830848) to match the other entries.

Answer (score 8):

## Recursive Prolog

```
fac(0,1).
fac(N,X) :- N1 is N -1, fac(N1, T), X is N * T.
```

## Tail Recursive Prolog

```
fac(0,N,N).
fac(X,N,T) :- A is N * X, X1 is X - 1, fac(X1,A,T).
fac(N,T) :- fac(N,1,T).
```

Answer (score 8):

## ruby recursive

```
(factorial=Hash.new{|h,k|k*h[k-1]})[1]=1
```

usage:

```
factorial[5]
 => 120
```

Comment: I would write that as (f=Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=k*h[k-1]})[1]=1
 or otherwise the calculated values are not stored

Answer (score 7):

**Scheme**

Here is a simple recursive definition:

```
(define (factorial x)
  (if (= x 0) 1
      (* x (factorial (- x 1)))))
```

In Scheme tail-recursive functions use constant stack space. Here is a version of factorial that is tail-recursive:

```
(define factorial
  (letrec ((fact (lambda (x accum)
                   (if (= x 0) accum
                       (fact (- x 1) (* accum x))))))
    (lambda (x)
      (fact x 1))))
```

Answer (score 7):

## [D Templates: Functional](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/template-comparison.html)

```
template factorial(int n : 1)
{
  const factorial = 1;
}

template factorial(int n)
{
  const factorial =
     n * factorial!(n-1);
}
```

or

```
template factorial(int n)
{
  static if(n == 1)
    const factorial = 1;
  else 
    const factorial =
       n * factorial!(n-1);
}
```

Used like this:

```
factorial!(5)
```

Comment: In the second example remove the " : 1 "

Comment: Thanks. Another example where the type is chosen on template instantiation:

template factorial(T, T n)
{
  static if(n == 1)
    const factorial = 1;
  else 
    const factorial =
       n * factorial!(T,n-1);
}


factorial!(int,5));

Answer (score 7):

Oddball examples? What about using the gamma function! Since, `Gamma n = (n-1)!`.

### OCaml: Using Gamma

```
let rec gamma z =
    let pi = 4.0 *. atan 1.0 in
    if z < 0.5 then
        pi /. ((sin (pi*.z)) *. (gamma (1.0 -. z)))
    else
        let consts = [| 0.99999999999980993; 676.5203681218851; -1259.1392167224028;
                        771.32342877765313; -176.61502916214059; 12.507343278686905;
                 -0.13857109526572012; 9.9843695780195716e-6; 1.5056327351493116e-7;
                     |] 
        in
        let z = z -. 1.0 in
        let results = Array.fold_right 
                          (fun x y -> x +. y)
                          (Array.mapi 
                              (fun i x -> if i = 0 then x else x /. (z+.(float i)))
                              consts
                          )
                          0.0
        in
        let x = z +. (float (Array.length consts)) -. 1.5 in
        let final = (sqrt (2.0*.pi)) *. 
                    (x ** (z+.0.5)) *.
                    (exp (-.x)) *. result
        in
        final

let factorial_gamma n = int_of_float (gamma (float (n+1)))
```

Answer (score 7):

Freshman Haskell programmer

```
fac n = if n == 0 
           then 1
           else n * fac (n-1)
```

Sophomore Haskell programmer, at MIT
(studied Scheme as a freshman)

```
fac = (\(n) ->
        (if ((==) n 0)
            then 1
            else ((*) n (fac ((-) n 1)))))
```

Junior Haskell programmer
(beginning Peano player)

```
fac  0    =  1
fac (n+1) = (n+1) * fac n
```

Another junior Haskell programmer
(read that n+k patterns are “a disgusting part of Haskell” [1]
and joined the “Ban n+k patterns”-movement [2])

```
fac 0 = 1
fac n = n * fac (n-1)
```

Senior Haskell programmer
(voted for   Nixon   Buchanan   Bush — “leans right”)

```
fac n = foldr (*) 1 [1..n]
```

Another senior Haskell programmer
(voted for   McGovern   Biafra   Nader — “leans left”)

```
fac n = foldl (*) 1 [1..n]
```

Yet another senior Haskell programmer
(leaned so far right he came back left again!)

```
-- using foldr to simulate foldl

fac n = foldr (\x g n -> g (x*n)) id [1..n] 1
```

Memoizing Haskell programmer
(takes Ginkgo Biloba daily)

```
facs = scanl (*) 1 [1..]

fac n = facs !! n
```

Pointless (ahem) “Points-free” Haskell programmer
(studied at Oxford)

```
fac = foldr (*) 1 . enumFromTo 1
```

Iterative Haskell programmer
(former Pascal programmer)

```
fac n = result (for init next done)
        where init = (0,1)
              next   (i,m) = (i+1, m * (i+1))
              done   (i,_) = i==n
              result (_,m) = m

for i n d = until d n i
```

Iterative one-liner Haskell programmer
(former APL and C programmer)

```
fac n = snd (until ((>n) . fst) (\(i,m) -> (i+1, i*m)) (1,1))
```

Accumulating Haskell programmer
(building up to a quick climax)

```
facAcc a 0 = a
facAcc a n = facAcc (n*a) (n-1)

fac = facAcc 1
```

Continuation-passing Haskell programmer
(raised RABBITS in early years, then moved to New Jersey)

```
facCps k 0 = k 1
facCps k n = facCps (k . (n *)) (n-1)

fac = facCps id
```

Boy Scout Haskell programmer
(likes tying knots; always “reverent,” he
belongs to the Church of the Least Fixed-Point [8])

```
y f = f (y f)

fac = y (\f n -> if (n==0) then 1 else n * f (n-1))
```

Combinatory Haskell programmer
(eschews variables, if not obfuscation;
all this currying’s just a phase, though it seldom hinders)

```
s f g x = f x (g x)

k x y   = x

b f g x = f (g x)

c f g x = f x g

y f     = f (y f)

cond p f g x = if p x then f x else g x

fac  = y (b (cond ((==) 0) (k 1)) (b (s (*)) (c b pred)))
```

List-encoding Haskell programmer
(prefers to count in unary)

```
arb = ()    -- "undefined" is also a good RHS, as is "arb" :)

listenc n = replicate n arb
listprj f = length . f . listenc

listprod xs ys = [ i (x,y) | x<-xs, y<-ys ]
                 where i _ = arb

facl []         = listenc  1
facl n@(_:pred) = listprod n (facl pred)

fac = listprj facl
```

Interpretive Haskell programmer
(never “met a language” he didn't like)

```
-- a dynamically-typed term language

data Term = Occ Var
          | Use Prim
          | Lit Integer
          | App Term Term
          | Abs Var  Term
          | Rec Var  Term

type Var  = String
type Prim = String


-- a domain of values, including functions

data Value = Num  Integer
           | Bool Bool
           | Fun (Value -> Value)

instance Show Value where
  show (Num  n) = show n
  show (Bool b) = show b
  show (Fun  _) = ""

prjFun (Fun f) = f
prjFun  _      = error "bad function value"

prjNum (Num n) = n
prjNum  _      = error "bad numeric value"

prjBool (Bool b) = b
prjBool  _       = error "bad boolean value"

binOp inj f = Fun (\i -> (Fun (\j -> inj (f (prjNum i) (prjNum j)))))


-- environments mapping variables to values

type Env = [(Var, Value)]

getval x env =  case lookup x env of
                  Just v  -> v
                  Nothing -> error ("no value for " ++ x)


-- an environment-based evaluation function

eval env (Occ x) = getval x env
eval env (Use c) = getval c prims
eval env (Lit k) = Num k
eval env (App m n) = prjFun (eval env m) (eval env n)
eval env (Abs x m) = Fun  (\v -> eval ((x,v) : env) m)
eval env (Rec x m) = f where f = eval ((x,f) : env) m


-- a (fixed) "environment" of language primitives

times = binOp Num  (*)

minus = binOp Num  (-)
equal = binOp Bool (==)
cond  = Fun (\b -> Fun (\x -> Fun (\y -> if (prjBool b) then x else y)))

prims = [ ("*", times), ("-", minus), ("==", equal), ("if", cond) ]


-- a term representing factorial and a "wrapper" for evaluation

facTerm = Rec "f" (Abs "n" 
              (App (App (App (Use "if")
                   (App (App (Use "==") (Occ "n")) (Lit 0))) (Lit 1))
                   (App (App (Use "*")  (Occ "n"))
                        (App (Occ "f")  
                             (App (App (Use "-") (Occ "n")) (Lit 1))))))

fac n = prjNum (eval [] (App facTerm (Lit n)))
```

Static Haskell programmer
(he does it with class, he’s got that fundep Jones!
After Thomas Hallgren’s “Fun with Functional Dependencies” [7])

```
-- static Peano constructors and numerals

data Zero
data Succ n

type One   = Succ Zero
type Two   = Succ One
type Three = Succ Two
type Four  = Succ Three


-- dynamic representatives for static Peanos

zero  = undefined :: Zero
one   = undefined :: One
two   = undefined :: Two
three = undefined :: Three
four  = undefined :: Four


-- addition, a la Prolog

class Add a b c | a b -> c where
  add :: a -> b -> c

instance              Add  Zero    b  b
instance Add a b c => Add (Succ a) b (Succ c)


-- multiplication, a la Prolog

class Mul a b c | a b -> c where
  mul :: a -> b -> c

instance                           Mul  Zero    b Zero
instance (Mul a b c, Add b c d) => Mul (Succ a) b d


-- factorial, a la Prolog

class Fac a b | a -> b where
  fac :: a -> b

instance                                Fac  Zero    One
instance (Fac n k, Mul (Succ n) k m) => Fac (Succ n) m

-- try, for "instance" (sorry):
-- 
--     :t fac four
```

Beginning graduate Haskell programmer
(graduate education tends to liberate one from petty concerns
about, e.g., the efficiency of hardware-based integers)

```
-- the natural numbers, a la Peano

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat


-- iteration and some applications

iter z s  Zero    = z
iter z s (Succ n) = s (iter z s n)

plus n = iter n     Succ
mult n = iter Zero (plus n)


-- primitive recursion

primrec z s  Zero    = z
primrec z s (Succ n) = s n (primrec z s n)


-- two versions of factorial

fac  = snd . iter (one, one) (\(a,b) -> (Succ a, mult a b))
fac' = primrec one (mult . Succ)


-- for convenience and testing (try e.g. "fac five")

int = iter 0 (1+)

instance Show Nat where
  show = show . int

(zero : one : two : three : four : five : _) = iterate Succ Zero
```

Origamist Haskell programmer
(always starts out with the “basic Bird fold”)

```
-- (curried, list) fold and an application

fold c n []     = n
fold c n (x:xs) = c x (fold c n xs)

prod = fold (*) 1


-- (curried, boolean-based, list) unfold and an application

unfold p f g x = 
  if p x 
     then [] 
     else f x : unfold p f g (g x)

downfrom = unfold (==0) id pred


-- hylomorphisms, as-is or "unfolded" (ouch! sorry ...)

refold  c n p f g   = fold c n . unfold p f g

refold' c n p f g x = 
  if p x 
     then n 
     else c (f x) (refold' c n p f g (g x))


-- several versions of factorial, all (extensionally) equivalent

fac   = prod . downfrom
fac'  = refold  (*) 1 (==0) id pred
fac'' = refold' (*) 1 (==0) id pred
```

Cartesianally-inclined Haskell programmer
(prefers Greek food, avoids the spicy Indian stuff;
inspired by Lex Augusteijn’s “Sorting Morphisms” [3])

```
-- (product-based, list) catamorphisms and an application

cata (n,c) []     = n
cata (n,c) (x:xs) = c (x, cata (n,c) xs)

mult = uncurry (*)
prod = cata (1, mult)


-- (co-product-based, list) anamorphisms and an application

ana f = either (const []) (cons . pair (id, ana f)) . f

cons = uncurry (:)

downfrom = ana uncount

uncount 0 = Left  ()
uncount n = Right (n, n-1)


-- two variations on list hylomorphisms

hylo  f  g    = cata g . ana f

hylo' f (n,c) = either (const n) (c . pair (id, hylo' f (c,n))) . f

pair (f,g) (x,y) = (f x, g y)


-- several versions of factorial, all (extensionally) equivalent

fac   = prod . downfrom
fac'  = hylo  uncount (1, mult)
fac'' = hylo' uncount (1, mult)
```

Ph.D. Haskell programmer
(ate so many bananas that his eyes bugged out, now he needs new lenses!)

```
-- explicit type recursion based on functors

newtype Mu f = Mu (f (Mu f))  deriving Show

in      x  = Mu x
out (Mu x) = x


-- cata- and ana-morphisms, now for *arbitrary* (regular) base functors

cata phi = phi . fmap (cata phi) . out
ana  psi = in  . fmap (ana  psi) . psi


-- base functor and data type for natural numbers,
-- using a curried elimination operator

data N b = Zero | Succ b  deriving Show

instance Functor N where
  fmap f = nelim Zero (Succ . f)

nelim z s  Zero    = z
nelim z s (Succ n) = s n

type Nat = Mu N


-- conversion to internal numbers, conveniences and applications

int = cata (nelim 0 (1+))

instance Show Nat where
  show = show . int

zero = in   Zero
suck = in . Succ       -- pardon my "French" (Prelude conflict)

plus n = cata (nelim n     suck   )
mult n = cata (nelim zero (plus n))


-- base functor and data type for lists

data L a b = Nil | Cons a b  deriving Show

instance Functor (L a) where
  fmap f = lelim Nil (\a b -> Cons a (f b))

lelim n c  Nil       = n
lelim n c (Cons a b) = c a b

type List a = Mu (L a)


-- conversion to internal lists, conveniences and applications

list = cata (lelim [] (:))

instance Show a => Show (List a) where
  show = show . list

prod = cata (lelim (suck zero) mult)

upto = ana (nelim Nil (diag (Cons . suck)) . out)

diag f x = f x x

fac = prod . upto
```

Post-doc Haskell programmer
(from Uustalu, Vene and Pardo’s “Recursion Schemes from Comonads” [4])

```
-- explicit type recursion with functors and catamorphisms

newtype Mu f = In (f (Mu f))

unIn (In x) = x

cata phi = phi . fmap (cata phi) . unIn


-- base functor and data type for natural numbers,
-- using locally-defined "eliminators"

data N c = Z | S c

instance Functor N where
  fmap g  Z    = Z
  fmap g (S x) = S (g x)

type Nat = Mu N

zero   = In  Z
suck n = In (S n)

add m = cata phi where
  phi  Z    = m
  phi (S f) = suck f

mult m = cata phi where
  phi  Z    = zero
  phi (S f) = add m f


-- explicit products and their functorial action

data Prod e c = Pair c e

outl (Pair x y) = x
outr (Pair x y) = y

fork f g x = Pair (f x) (g x)

instance Functor (Prod e) where
  fmap g = fork (g . outl) outr


-- comonads, the categorical "opposite" of monads

class Functor n => Comonad n where
  extr :: n a -> a
  dupl :: n a -> n (n a)

instance Comonad (Prod e) where
  extr = outl
  dupl = fork id outr


-- generalized catamorphisms, zygomorphisms and paramorphisms

gcata :: (Functor f, Comonad n) =>
           (forall a. f (n a) -> n (f a))
             -> (f (n c) -> c) -> Mu f -> c

gcata dist phi = extr . cata (fmap phi . dist . fmap dupl)

zygo chi = gcata (fork (fmap outl) (chi . fmap outr))

para :: Functor f => (f (Prod (Mu f) c) -> c) -> Mu f -> c
para = zygo In


-- factorial, the *hard* way!

fac = para phi where
  phi  Z             = suck zero
  phi (S (Pair f n)) = mult f (suck n)


-- for convenience and testing

int = cata phi where
  phi  Z    = 0
  phi (S f) = 1 + f

instance Show (Mu N) where
  show = show . int
```

Tenured professor
(teaching Haskell to freshmen)

```
fac n = product [1..n]
```

Comment: Wow! I have no idea what he's talking about, but I'm sure if I understood it it would be really funny.

Answer (score 6):

PowerShell

```
function factorial( [int] $n ) 
{ 
    $result = 1; 

    if ( $n -gt 1 ) 
    { 
        $result = $n * ( factorial ( $n - 1 ) ) 
    } 

    $result 
}
```

Here's a one-liner:

```
$n..1 | % {$result = 1}{$result *= $_}{$result}
```

Answer (score 6):

## Java 1.6: recursive, memoized (for subsequent calls)

```
private static Map<BigInteger, BigInteger> _results = new HashMap()

public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger n){
    if (0 >= n.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE))
       return BigInteger.ONE.max(n);
    if (_results.containsKey(n))
       return _results.get(n);
    BigInteger result = factorial(n.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)).multiply(n);
    _results.put(n, result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nice. And you can seed the memo-map to get the performance of the C# lookup approach.

Answer (score 6):

## Bash: Recursive

In bash and recursive, but with the added advantage that it deals with each iteration in a new process. The max it can calculate is !20 before overflowing, but you can still run it for big numbers if you don't care about the answer and want your system to fall over ;)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(($1 * `( [[ $1 -gt 1 ]] && ./$0 $(($1 - 1)) ) || echo 1`));
```

Answer (score 5):

**C/C++**: Procedural

```
unsigned long factorial(int n)
{
    unsigned long factorial = 1;
    int i;

    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++)
        factorial *= i;

    return factorial;
}
```

**PHP**: Procedural

```
function factorial($n)
{
    for ($factorial = 1, $i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++)
        $factorial *= $i;

    return $factorial;
}
```

[@Niyaz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930/factorial-algorithms-in-different-languages#23979): You didn't specify return type for the function

Comment: You really need to make sure n and $n are not negative!

Answer (score 5):

The problem with most of the above is that they will run out of precision at about 25! (12! with 32 bit ints) or just overflow. Here's a c# implementation to break through these limits!

```
class Number
{
  public Number ()
  {
    m_number = "0";
  }

  public Number (string value)
  {
    m_number = value;
  }

  public int this [int column]
  {
    get
    {
      return column < m_number.Length ? m_number [m_number.Length - column - 1] - '0' : 0;
    }
  }

  public static implicit operator Number (string rhs)
  {
    return new Number (rhs);
  }

  public static bool operator == (Number lhs, Number rhs)
  {
    return lhs.m_number == rhs.m_number;
  }

  public static bool operator != (Number lhs, Number rhs)
  {
    return lhs.m_number != rhs.m_number;
  }

  public override bool Equals (object obj)
  {
     return this == (Number) obj;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode ()
  {
    return m_number.GetHashCode ();
  }

  public static Number operator + (Number lhs, Number rhs)
  {
    StringBuilder
      result = new StringBuilder (new string ('0', lhs.m_number.Length + rhs.m_number.Length));

    int
      carry = 0;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < result.Length ; ++i)
    {
      int
        sum = carry + lhs [i] + rhs [i],
        units = sum % 10;

      carry = sum / 10;

      result [result.Length - i - 1] = (char) ('0' + units);
    }

    return TrimLeadingZeros (result);
  }

  public static Number operator * (Number lhs, Number rhs)
  {
    StringBuilder
      result = new StringBuilder (new string ('0', lhs.m_number.Length + rhs.m_number.Length));

    for (int multiplier_index = rhs.m_number.Length - 1 ; multiplier_index >= 0 ; --multiplier_index)
    {
      int
        multiplier = rhs.m_number [multiplier_index] - '0',
        column = result.Length - rhs.m_number.Length + multiplier_index;

      for (int i = lhs.m_number.Length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i, --column)
      {
        int
          product = (lhs.m_number [i] - '0') * multiplier,
          units = product % 10,
          tens = product / 10,
          hundreds = 0,
          unit_sum = result [column] - '0' + units;

        if (unit_sum > 9)
        {
          unit_sum -= 10;
          ++tens;
        }

        result [column] = (char) ('0' + unit_sum);

        int
          tens_sum = result [column - 1] - '0' + tens;

        if (tens_sum > 9)
        {
          tens_sum -= 10;
          ++hundreds;
        }

        result [column - 1] = (char) ('0' + tens_sum);

        if (hundreds > 0)
        {
          int
            hundreds_sum = result [column - 2] - '0' + hundreds;

          result [column - 2] = (char) ('0' + hundreds_sum);
        }
      }
    }

    return TrimLeadingZeros (result);
  }

  public override string ToString ()
  {
    return m_number;
  }

  static string TrimLeadingZeros (StringBuilder number)
  {
    while (number [0] == '0' && number.Length > 1)
    {
      number.Remove (0, 1);
    }

    return number.ToString ();
  }

  string
    m_number;
}

static void Main (string [] args)
{
  Number
    a = new Number ("1"),
    b = new Number (args [0]),
    one = new Number ("1");

  for (Number c = new Number ("1") ; c != b ; )
  {
    c = c + one;
    a = a * c;
  }

  Console.WriteLine (string.Format ("{0}! = {1}", new object [] { b, a }));
}
```

FWIW: 10000! is over 35500 character long.

Skizz

Comment: Isn't there a decimal type in C#? Using strings? ouch! What about GMP (the GNU MultiPrecision library in C, used by many languages for bignums).

Comment: The decimal type has finite range, only much greater than doubles. Strings are really easy to print. You could use base 256 which would simplify the code a bit but would be awkward to convert to string. Swings and roundabouts I guess.

Comment: @Alexander Prokofyev: Lots of languages have built-in bignum support.

Answer (score 5):

## Lambda Calculus

Input and output are Church numerals (i.e. natural number `k` is `\f n. f^k n`; so `3 = \f n. f (f (f n)))`

```
(\x. x x) (\y f. f (y y f)) (\y n. n (\x y z. z) (\x y. x) (\f n. f n) (\f. n (y (\f m. n (\g h. h (g f)) (\x. m) (\x. x)) f)))
```

Answer (score 5):

The code below is tongue in cheek, however when you consider that the return value is limited to n < 34 for uint32, <65 uint64 before we run out of space for the return value with a uint, **hard coding 33 values isn't that crazy** :)

```
public static int Factorial(int n)
{
    switch (n)
    {
        case 1:
            return 1;
        case 2:
            return 2;
        case 3:
            return 6;
        case 4:
            return 24;
        default:
            throw new Exception("Sorry, I can only count to 4");
    }

}
```

Comment: Funny, very non useful though.

Comment: there is so much truth here - who needs factorials in a C-like language anyway ?

Comment: why not use an array instead?

Answer (score 4):

**Ruby: functional**

```
def factorial(n)
    return 1 if n == 1
    n * factorial(n -1)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

## Icon

### Recursive function

```
procedure factorial(n)
  return (0<n) * factorial(n-1) | 1
end
```

I've cheated a bit allowing negatives to return 1. If you want it to fail given a negative argument it's slightly less concise:

```
  return (0<n) * factorial(n-1) | (n=0 & 1)
```

Then

```
write(factorial(3))
write(factorial(-1))
write(factorial(20))
```

prints

```
6
2432902008176640000
```

### Iterative generator

```
procedure factorials()
  local f,n
  f := 1; n := 0
  repeat suspend f *:= (n +:= 1)
end
```

Then

```
every write(factorials() \ 5)
```

prints

```
1
2
6
24
120
```

To understand this: evaluation is goal-directed and backtracks on failure. There is no boolean type, and binary operators which would return a boolean in other languages, either fail or return their second argument - with the exception of |, which in a single-value context returns its first argument if it succeeds, otherwise tries its second argument. (in a multiple-value context it returns its first argument *then* its second argument)

`suspend` is like `yield` in other languages, except that a generator is not explicitly called multiple times to return its results. Instead,
`every` asks its argument for all values but doesn't return anything by default; it's useful with side-effects (in this case I/O).

`\` limits the number of values returned by a generator, which in the case of `factorials` would be infinite.

Answer (score 4):

## Clojure

### Tail-recursive

```
(defn fact 
  ([n] (fact n 1))
  ([n acc] (if (= n 0) 
               acc 
               (recur (- n 1) (* acc n)))))
```

### Short and simple

```
 (defn fact [n] (apply * (range 1 (+ n 1))))
```

Comment: I was about to post: (defn fac [n] (reduce * (range 1 (inc n)))), but then I saw yours :)

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell

```
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is as fast as **bash** & **bc**:

```
function fac { seq $1 | paste -sd* | bc; }  
$ fac 42
1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000
$
```

Answer (score 3):

**Mathematica** : using pure recursive functions

```
(If[#>1,# #0[#-1],1])&
```

Answer (score 3):

## Lua

```
function factorial (n)
  if (n <= 1) then return 1 end
  return n*factorial(n-1)
end
```

And here is a stack overflow caught in the wild:

```
> print (factorial(234132))
stdin:3: stack overflow
stack traceback:
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    ...
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:3: in function 'factorial'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Answer (score 3):

Agda 2: Functional, dependently typed.

```
data Nat = zero | suc (m::Nat)

add (m::Nat) (n::Nat) :: Nat
 = case m of
     (zero ) -> n
     (suc p) -> suc (add p n)

mul (m::Nat) (n::Nat)::Nat
   = case m of
      (zero ) -> zero
      (suc p) -> add n (mul p n)

factorial (n::Nat)::Nat 
 = case n of
    (zero ) -> suc zero
    (suc p) -> mul n (factorial p)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Delphi

```
facts: array[2..12] of integer;

function TForm1.calculate(f: integer): integer;
begin
    if f = 1 then
      Result := f
    else if f > High(facts) then
      Result := High(Integer)
    else if (facts[f] > 0) then
      Result := facts[f]
    else begin
      facts[f] := f * Calculate(f-1);
      Result := facts[f];
    end;
end;

initialize

  for i := Low(facts) to High(facts) do
    facts[i] := 0;
```

After the first time a factorial higher or equal to the desired value has been calculated, this algorithm just returns the factorial in constant time O(1).

It takes in account that int32 only can hold up to 12!

Comment: I really dislike Delphi, but I love the fact this algorithm (unlike most of the others on this page) takes into account that factorial results don't change (and for large n are expensive) and you might as well only calculate a particular value once.

Answer (score 3):

Nemerle: Functional

```
def fact(n) {
    | 0 => 1
    | x => x * fact(x-1)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#Language: T-SQL
#Style: Recursive, divide and conquer
```

Just for fun - in T-SQL using a divide and conquer recursive method. Yes, recursive - in SQL without stack overflow.

```
create function factorial(@b int=1, @e int) returns float as begin
  return case when @b>=@e then @e else 
      convert(float,dbo.factorial(@b,convert(int,@b+(@e-@b)/2)))
    * convert(float,dbo.factorial(convert(int,@b+1+(@e-@b)/2),@e)) end
end
```

call it like this:

```
print dbo.factorial(1,170) -- the 1 being the starting number
```

Answer (score 3):

## PostScript: Tail Recursive

```
/fact0 { dup 2 lt { pop } { 2 copy mul 3 1 roll 1 sub exch pop fact0 } ifelse } def
/fact { 1 exch fact0 } def
```

Answer (score 3):

Forth (recursive):

```
: factorial ( n -- n )
    dup 1 > if
        dup 1 - recurse *
    else
        drop 1
     then
;
```

Answer (score 3):

## Scala

The factorial can be defined functionally as:

```
def fact(n: Int): BigInt = 1 to n reduceLeft(_*_)
```

or more traditionally as

```
def fact(n: Int): BigInt = if (n == 0) 1 else fact(n-1) * n
```

and we can make ! a valid method on Ints:

```
object extendBuiltins extends Application {

  class Factorizer(n: Int) {
    def ! = 1 to n reduceLeft(_*_)
  }

  implicit def int2fact(n: Int) = new Factorizer(n)

  println("10! = " + (10!))
}
```

Comment: If you want to enable the scala tail recursion optimisation for the traditional funtion do:  def fact(n: Int,acc: BigInt): BigInt = if (n == 0) acc else fact(n-1,acc*n)    . And call 5! with fact(5,1)

Answer (score 3):

Compile time in C++

```
template<unsigned i>
struct factorial
{ static const unsigned value = i * factorial<i-1>::value; };

template<>
struct factorial<0>
{ static const unsigned value = 1; };
```

Use in code as:

```
Factorial<5>::value
```

Answer (score 3):

Java Script: Creative method using "interview question" counting bits fnc.

```
function nu(x)
{
  var r=0
  while( x ) {
    x &= x-1
    r++
  }
  return r
}

function fac(n)
{
  var r= Math.pow(2,n-nu(n))

  for ( var i=3 ; i <= n ; i+= 2 )
    r *= Math.pow(i,Math.floor(Math.log(n/i)/Math.LN2)+1)
  return r
}
```

Works up to 21! then Chrome switches to scientific notation.  Inspiration thanks lack of sleep and Knuth, et al's "concrete mathematics".

Answer (score 3):

## Brainfuck: with bignum support!

Accepts as input a non-negative integer followed by newline, and outputs the corresponding factorial followed by newline.

```
>>>>,----------[>>>>,----------]>>>>++<<<<<<<<[>++++++[<----
-->-]<-<<<<]>>>>[[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>-]<->+<[>>>>+<<<-<[-]]>[-]
>>]>[-<<<<<[<<<<]>>>>[[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>-]>>]>>>>[-[>+<-]+>>>
>]<<<<[<<<<]<<<<[<<<<]>>>>>[>>>[>>>>]>>>>[>>>>]<<<<[[>>>>+<<
<<-]<<<<]>>>>+<<<<<<<[<<<<]>>>>-[>>>[>>>>]>>>>[>>>>]<<<<[>>>
+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>+>-]<-[>>+<<[-]]<<[<<<<]>>>>[>[>+<-]>[<<+>+>
-]<<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[<<<+>>+>-]<->+++++++++[-<[-[>>>>+<<<<-]]>>
>>[<<<<+>>>>-]<<<]<[>>+<<<<[-]>>[<<+>>-]]>>]<<<<[<<<<]<<<[<<
<<]>>>>-]>>>>]>>>[>[-]>>>]<<<<[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>-]<->+<[>-<[-
]]>[-<<-<<<<[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>-]<->+<[>-<[-]]>]<<[<<<<]<<<<-[
>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>-]+<[>-<[-]]>[-<<++++++++++<<<<-[>>+<<-]>>[<
<+>+>-]+<[>-<[-]]>]<<[<<<<]>>>>[[>>+<<-]>>[<<+>+>-]<->+<[>>>
>+<<<-<[-]]>[-]>>]>]>>>[>>>>]<<<<[>+++++++[<+++++++>-]<--.<<
<<]++++++++++.
```

Unlike the brainf*ck answer posted earlier, this *does not* overflow any memory locations.  (That implementation put n! in a single memory location, effectively limiting it to n less than 6 under standard bf rules.)  This program will output n! for any value of n, limited only by time and memory (or bf implementation).  For example, using Urban Muller's compiler on my machine, it takes 12 seconds to compute 1000!  I think that's pretty good, considering the program can only move left/right and increment/decrement by one.

Believe it or not, this is the first bf program I've written; it took about 10 hours, which were mostly spent debugging.  Unfortunately, I later found out that Daniel B Cristofani has written a [factorial generator](http://www.hevanet.com/cristofd/brainfuck/factorial.b), which just outputs ever-larger factorials, never terminating:

```
>++++++++++>>>+>+[>>>+[-[<<<<<[+<<<<<]>>[[-]>[<<+>+>-]<[>+<-
]<[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>+<-[>[-]>>>>+>+<
<<<<<-[>+<-]]]]]]]]]]]>[<+>-]+>>>>>]<<<<<[<<<<<]>>>>>>>[>>>>
>]++[-<<<<<]>>>>>>-]+>>>>>]<[>++<-]<<<<[<[>+<-]<<<<]>>[->[-]
++++++[<++++++++>-]>>>>]<<<<<[<[>+>+<<-]>.<<<<<]>.>>>>]
```

His program is much shorter, but he's practically a professional bf golfer.

Answer (score 3):

### Agda2

It is Agda2, using the very nice Agda2 syntax.

```
module fac where

data Nat : Set where        -- Peano numbers
  zero : Nat
  suc : Nat -> Nat
{-# BUILTIN NATURAL Nat #-}
{-# BUILTIN SUC suc #-}
{-# BUILTIN ZERO zero #-}

infixl 10 _+_               -- Addition over Peano numbers
_+_ : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
zero + n    = n
(suc n) + m = suc (n + m)

infixl 20 _*_               -- Multiplication over Peano numbers
_*_ : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
zero * n = zero
n * zero = zero
(suc n) * (suc m) = suc n + (suc n * m)

_! : Nat -> Nat             -- Factorial function, syntax: "x !"
zero ! = suc zero
(suc n) ! = (suc n) * (n !)
```

Answer (score 3):

**Python:**
functional, recursive one-liner using short circuit boolean evaluation.

```
    factorial = lambda n: ((n <= 1) and 1) or factorial(n-1) * n
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 6: Functional

```
multi factorial ( Int $n where { $n <= 0 } ){
  return 1;
}
multi factorial ( Int $n ){
   return $n * factorial( $n-1 );
}
```

This will also work:

```
multi factorial(0) { 1 }
multi factorial(Int $n) { $n * factorial($n - 1) }
```

*Check [Jonathan Worthington's](http://use.perl.org/~JonathanWorthington/journal/39196?from=StackOverflow) journal on [use.perl.org](http://use.perl.org), for more information about the last example.*

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 6:Procedural

```
sub factorial ( int $n ){

  my $result = 1;

  loop ( ; $n > 0; $n-- ){

    $result *= $n;

  }

  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

C:

Edit: Actually C++ I guess, because of the variable declaration in the for loop.

```
 int factorial(int x) {
      int product = 1;

      for (int i = x; i > 0; i--) {
           product *= i;
      }

      return product;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript:

```
factorial = function( n )
{
   return n > 0 ? n * factorial( n - 1 ) : 1;
}
```

I'm not sure what a Factorial is but that does what the other programs do in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

**Python:**

Recursive

```
def fact(x): 
    return (1 if x==0 else x * fact(x-1))
```

Using iterator

```
import operator

def fact(x):
    return reduce(operator.mul, xrange(1, x+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

two of many Mathematica solutions (although ! is built-in and efficient):

```
(* returns pure function *)
(FixedPoint[(If[#[[2]]>1,{#[[1]]*#[[2]],#[[2]]-1},#])&,{1,n}][[1]])&

(* not using built-in, returns pure function, don't use: might build 1..n list *)
(Times @@ Range[#])&
```

Answer (score 2):

## Visual Basic: Linq

```
<Extension()> _
Public Function Product(ByVal xs As IEnumerable(Of Integer)) As Integer
    Return xs.Aggregate(1, Function(a, b) a * b)
End Function

Public Function Fact(ByVal n As Integer) As Integer
    Return Aggregate x In Enumerable.Range(1, n) Into Product()
End Function
```

This shows how to use the `Aggregate` keyword in VB. **C# can't do this** (although C# can of course call the extension method directly).

Answer (score 2):

## Scheme : Functional - Tail Recursive

```
(define (factorial n)
  (define (fac-times n acc)
    (if (= n 0)
        acc
        (fac-times (- n 1) (* acc n))))
  (if (< n 0)
      (display "Wrong argument!")
      (fac-times n 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby: Iterative

```
def factorial(n)
  (1 .. n).inject{|a, b| a*b}
end
```

## Ruby: Recursive

```
def factorial(n)
  n == 1 ? 1 : n * factorial(n-1)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#Language: T-SQL
#Style: Big Numbers
```

Here's another T-SQL solution -- supports big numbers in a most Rube Goldbergian manner. Lots of set-based ops. Tried to keep it uniquely SQL. Horrible performance (400! took 33 seconds on a Dell Latitude D830)

```
create function bigfact(@x varchar(max)) returns varchar(max) as begin
  declare @c int
  declare @n table(n int,e int)
  declare @f table(n int,e int)

  set @c=0
  while @c<len(@x) begin
    set @c=@c+1
    insert @n(n,e) values(convert(int,substring(@x,@c,1)),len(@x)-@c)
  end

  -- our current factorial
  insert @f(n,e) select 1,0

  while 1=1 begin
    declare @p table(n int,e int)
    delete @p
    -- product
    insert @p(n,e) select sum(f.n*n.n), f.e+n.e from @f f cross join @n n group by f.e+n.e

    -- normalize
    while 1=1 begin
      delete @f
      insert @f(n,e) select sum(n),e from (
        select (n % 10) as n,e from @p union all 
        select (n/10) % 10,e+1 from @p union all 
        select (n/100) %10,e+2 from @p union all 
        select (n/1000)%10,e+3 from @p union all 
        select (n/10000) % 10,e+4 from @p union all 
        select (n/100000)% 10,e+5 from @p union all 
        select (n/1000000)%10,e+6 from @p union all 
        select (n/10000000) % 10,e+7 from @p union all 
        select (n/100000000)% 10,e+8 from @p union all 
        select (n/1000000000)%10,e+9 from @p
      ) f group by e having sum(n)>0

      set @c=0
      select @c=count(*) from @f where n>9
      if @c=0 break
      delete @p
      insert @p(n,e) select n,e from @f
    end

    -- decrement
    update @n set n=n-1 where e=0

    -- normalize
    while 1=1 begin
      declare @e table(e int)
      delete @e
      insert @e(e) select e from @n where n<0
      if @@rowcount=0 break

      update @n set n=n+10 where e in (select e from @e)
      update @n set n=n-1 where e in (select e+1 from @e)
    end  

    set @c=0
    select @c=count(*) from @n where n>0
    if @c=0 break
  end

  select @c=max(e) from @f
  set @x=''
  declare @l varchar(max)
  while @c>=0 begin
    set @l='0'
    select @l=convert(varchar(max),n) from @f where e=@c
    set @x=@x+@l
    set @c=@c-1
  end
  return @x
end
```

Example:

```
print dbo.bigfact('69')
```

returns:

```
171122452428141311372468338881272839092270544893520369393648040923257279754140647424000000000000000
```

Answer (score 2):

## Language Name: [ChucK](http://chuck.cs.princeton.edu/)

```
Moog moog => dac;
4.0 => moog.gain;

for (0 => int i; i < 8; i++) {
    <<< factorial(i) >>>;
}

fun int factorial(int n) {
    1 => int result;
    if (n != 0) {
        n * factorial(n - 1) => result;
    }

    Std.mtof(result % 128) => moog.freq;
    0.25::second => now;

    return result;
}
```

And it sounds like [this](http://www.automatous-monk.com/mp3s/misc/Factorial.mp3).  Not terribly interesting, but, hey, it's just a factorial function!

Answer (score 2):

Simple solutions are the best:

```
#include <stdexcept>;

long fact(long f)
{
    static long fact [] = { 1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800, 39916800, 479001600, 1932053504, 1278945280, 2004310016, 2004189184 };
    static long max     = sizeof(fact)/sizeof(long);

    if ((f < 0) || (f >= max))
    {   throw std::range_error("Factorial Range Error");
    }

    return fact[f];
}
```

Comment: simple, but wrong !
Thats why I hate languages without builtin arbitrary precision arithmetic !

Comment: @blabla999: Not sure what you mean. This all integer based (this is not floating point).

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp: Lisp as God intended it to be used (that is, with LOOP)

```
(defun fact (n)
  (loop for i from 1 to n
        for acc = 1 then (* acc i)
        finally (return acc)))
```

Now, if someone can come up with a version based on FORMAT...

Comment: mhmh - I always though god made pure lisp - and the devil added the rest... (just kidding)

Answer (score 2):

## Common Lisp: FORMAT (obfuscated)

Okay, so I'll give it a try myself.

```
(defun format-fact (stream arg colonp atsignp &rest args)
  (destructuring-bind (n acc) arg
    (format stream
            "~[~A~:;~*~/format-fact/~]"
            (1- n)
            acc
            (list (1- n) (* acc n)))))

(defun fact (n)
  (parse-integer (format nil "~/format-fact/" (list n 1))))
```

There has to be a nicer, even more obscure FORMAT-based implementation.  This one is pretty straight-forward and boring, simply using FORMAT as an IF replacement.  Obviously, I'm not a FORMAT expert.

Answer (score 2):

**AWK**

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
    result=1;
    for(i=$1;i>0;i--){
        result=result*i;
    }
    print result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#Language: T-SQL, C#
#Style: Custom Aggregate
```

Another crazy way would be to create a custom aggregate and apply it over a temporary table of the integers 1..n.

```
/* ProductAggregate.cs */
using System;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(Format.Native)]
public struct product {
  private SqlDouble accum;
  public void Init() { accum = 1; }
  public void Accumulate(SqlDouble value) { accum *= value; }
  public void Merge(product value) { Accumulate(value.Terminate()); }
  public SqlDouble Terminate() { return accum; }
}
```

add this to sql

```
create assembly ProductAggregate from 'ProductAggregate.dll' with permission_set=safe -- mod path to point to actual dll location on disk.

create aggregate product(@a float) returns float external name ProductAggregate.product
```

create the table (there should be a built-in way to do this in SQL -- hmm. a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58429/sql-set-based-range) for SO?)

```
select 1 as n into #n union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5
```

then finally

```
select dbo.product(n) from #n
```

Answer (score 2):

Haskell:

```
factorial n = product [1..n]
```

Answer (score 2):

## **Eiffel**

```
class
    APPLICATION
inherit
    ARGUMENTS

create
    make

feature -- Initialization

    make is
            -- Run application.
        local
            l_fact: NATURAL_64
        do
            l_fact := factorial(argument(1).to_natural_64)
            print("Result is: " + l_fact.out)
        end

    factorial(n: NATURAL_64): NATURAL_64 is
            --
        require
            positive_n: n >= 0
        do
            if n = 0 then
                Result := 1
            else
                Result := n * factorial(n-1)
            end
        end

end -- class APPLICATION
```

Answer (score 2):

## befunge-93

```
                                    v
>v"Please enter a number (1-16) : "0<
,:             >$*99g1-:99p#v_.25*,@
^_&:1-99p>:1-:!|10          < 
         ^     <
```

An esoteric language by Chris Pressey of [Cat's Eye Technologies](http://catseye.tc/).

Answer (score 2):

**Perl (Y-combinator/Functional)**

```
print sub {
  my $f = shift;
  sub {
    my $f1 = shift;
    $f->( sub { $f1->( $f1 )->( @_ ) } )
  }->( sub {
    my $f2 = shift;
    $f->( sub { $f2->( $f2 )->( @_ ) } )
  } )
}->( sub {
  my $h = shift;
  sub {
    my $n = shift;
    return 1 if $n <=1;
    return $n * $h->($n-1);
  }
})->(5);
```

Everything after 'print' and before the '->(5)' represents the subroutine.
The factorial part is in the final "sub {...}". Everything else is to implement the Y-combinator.

Comment: Definitely one of the weirdest.

Answer (score 2):

## J

```
   fact=. verb define
*/ >:@i. y
)
```

Answer (score 2):

### Smalltalk, using a closure

```
    fac := [ :x | x = 0 ifTrue: [ 1 ] ifFalse: [ x * (fac value: x -1) ]].

    Transcript show: (fac value: 24) "-> 620448401733239439360000"
```

NB does not work in Squeak, requires full closures.

Answer (score 2):

### Smalltalk, memoized

Define a method on Dictionary

```
Dictionary >> fac: x
    ^self at: x ifAbsentPut: [ x * (self fac: x - 1) ]
```

usage

```
 d := Dictionary new.
 d at: 0 put: 1.
 d fac: 24
```

Answer (score 2):

### Smalltalk, 1-Liner

```
(1 to: 24) inject: 1 into: [ :a :b | a * b ]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica: non-recursive

```
fact[n_] := Times @@ Range[n]
```

Which is syntactic sugar for `Apply[Times, Range[n]]`.  I think that's the best way to do it, not counting the built-in `n!`, of course.  Note that that automatically uses bignums.

Answer (score 2):

Common Lisp version:

```
(defun ! (n) (reduce #'* (loop for i from 2 below (+ n 1) collect i)))
```

Seems to be quite fast.

```
* (! 42)

1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000
```

Comment: Why don't you loop for i from 2 upto n, instead of from 2 below (+ n 1)?

Comment: As you note, it's pretty fast on modern hardware, but it does use more memory than it needs to: it makes an O(n) list.  Unfortunately, there's no built-in for LOOP for it, though ITERATE does provide a MULTIPLY clause.

Answer (score 2):

## Delphi iterative

While recursion can be the only decent solution to a problem, for factorials it is not. To describe it, yes. To program it, no. Iteration is cheapest.

This function calculates factorials for somewhat larger arguments.

```
function Factorial(aNumber: Int64): String;
var
  F: Double;
begin
  F := 0;
  while aNumber > 1 do begin
    F := F + log10(aNumber);
    dec(aNumber);
  end;
  Result := FloatToStr(Power(10, Frac(F))) + ' * 10^' + IntToStr(Trunc(F));
end;
```

1000000! = 8.2639327850046 * 10^5565708

Comment: I wanted to see many ways of writing a simple, well understood algorithm.

Comment: Do I understand that this doesn't qualify?
5! = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5
therefore
ln(5!) = ln(1) + ln(2) + ln(3) + ln(4) + ln(5)
I must admit that I was kind of proud of myself when I "invented" this to compute large factorials on my TI-57, just for fun, many moons ago when I was 16.

Answer (score 2):

## Logo

```
? to factorial :n
> ifelse :n = 0 [output 1] [output :n * factorial :n - 1]
> end
```

And to invoke:

```
? print factorial 5
120
```

This is using the UCBLogo dialect of logo.

Answer (score 2):

Perl, pessimal:

```
# Because there are just so many other ways to get programs wrong...
use strict;
use warnings;

sub factorial {
    my ($x)=@_;

    for(my $f=1;;$f++) {
        my $tmp=$f;
        foreach my $g (1..$x) {
           $tmp/=$g;
        }
        return $f if $tmp == 1;
    }
}
```

I trust I get extra points for not using the '*' operator...

Comment: At least you started it out right, by using strict, and warnings.

Answer (score 2):

***NIX Shell**

Linux version:

```
seq -s'*' 42 | bc
```

BSD version:

```
jot -s'*' 42 | bc
```

Answer (score 2):

FORTH, iterative 1 liner

```
: FACT 1 SWAP 1 + 1 DO I * LOOP ;
```

Answer (score 2):

## Scheme evolution

### Regular Scheme program:

```
(define factorial
   (lambda (n)
     (if (= n 0)
         1
         (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
```

Should work, but notice that calling this function on large numbers will extend the stack on every recursion, which is bad in languages like C and Java.

### Continuation-passing style

```
(define factorial
  (lambda (n)
    (factorial_cps n (lambda (k) k))))

(define factorial_cps
  (lambda (n k)
    (if (zero? n)
        (k 1)
        (factorial (- n 1) (lambda (v)
                             (k (* n v)))))))
```

Ah, this way, we don't grow our stack every recursion because we can extend a continuation instead.  However, C doesn't have continuations.

### Representation-independent CPS

```
(define factorial
  (lambda (n)
    (factorial_cps n (k_))))

(define factorial_cps
  (lambda (n k)
    (if (zero? n)
        (apply_k 1)
        (factorial (- n 1) (k_extend n k))))

(define apply_k
  (lambda (ko v)
    (ko v)))
(define kt_empty
  (lambda ()
    (lambda (v) v)))
(define kt_extend 
  (lambda ()
    (lambda (v)
      (apply_k k (* n v)))))
```

Notice that responsibility for representation of the continuations used in the original CPS program has been shifted to the `kt_` helper procedures.

### Representation-independent CPS using ParentheC unions

Since representation of the continuations is in the helper procedures, we can switch to using [ParentheC](https://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/lkuper/b521/_media/parenthec.pdf) instead, with `kt_` being a type designator.

```
(define factorial
  (lambda (n)
    (factorial_cps n (kt_empty))))

(define factorial_cps
  (lambda (n k)
    (if (zero? n)
        (apply_k 1)
        (factorial (- n 1) (kt_extend n k))))

(define-union kt
  (empty)
  (extend n k))
(define apply_k
  (lambda ()
    (union-case kh kt
      [(empty) v]
      [(extend n k) (begin
                      (set! kh k)
                      (set! v (* n v))
                      (apply_k))])))
```

### Trampolined, registerized ParentheC program

That's not enough.  We now replace all function calls by instead setting global variables and a program counter.  Procedures are now labels suitable for GOTO statements.

```
(define-registers n k kh v)
(define-program-counter pc)

(define-label main
  (begin
    (set! n 5) ; what is the factorial of 5??
    (set! pc factorial_cps)
    (mount-trampoline kt_empty k pc)
    (printf "Factorial of 5: ~d\n" v)))

(define-label factorial_cps
  (if (zero? n)
      (begin
        (set! kh k)
        (set! v 1)
        (set! pc apply_k))
      (begin
        (set! k (kt_extend n k))
        (set! n (- n 1))
        (set! pc factorial_cps))))

(define-union kt
  (empty dismount) ; get off the trampoline!
  (extend n k))

(define-label apply_k
  (union-case kh kt
    [(empty dismount) (dismount-trampoline dismount)]
    [(extend n k) (begin
                    (set! kh k)
                    (set! v (* n v))
                    (set! pc apply_k))]))
```

Oh look, we have a `main` procedure now too.  Now all that's left to do is save this file as `fact5.pc` and run it through ParentheC's pc2c:

```
> (load "pc2c.ss")
> (pc2c "fact5.pc" "fact5.c" "fact5.h")
```

Could it be?  We got `fact5.c` and `fact5.h`.  Let's see...

```
$ gcc fact5.c -o fact5
$ ./fact5
Factorial of 5: 120
```

Success! We have converted a recursive Scheme program into a non-recursive C program! And it only took several hours and many forehead-shaped impressions in the wall to do it!  For convenience, [fact5.c](http://pastebin.ca/1881437) and 
 and [fact5.h](http://pastebin.ca/1881438).

Answer (score 1):

C++

```
factorial(int n)
{
    for(int i=1, f = 1; i<=n; i++)
        f *= i;
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java**: functional

```
int factorial(int x) {
    return x == 0 ? 1 : x * factorial(x-1);
}
```

Comment: yeah, well, funny if you don't have tail call optimization.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell: Functional

```
 fact 0 = 1
 fact n = n * fact (n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one not only calculates n!, it is also O(n!). It may have problems if you want to calculate anything "big" though.

```
long f(long n)
{
    long r=1;
    for (long i=1; i<n; i++)
        r=r*i;
    return r;
}

long factorial(long n)
{
    // iterative implementation should be efficient
    long result;
    for (long i=0; i<f(n); i++)
        result=result+1;
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Bourne Shell: Functional**

```
factorial() {
  if [ $1 -eq 0 ]
  then
    echo 1
    return
  fi

  a=`expr $1 - 1`
  expr $1 \* `factorial $a`
}
```

Also works for Korn Shell and Bourne Again Shell. :-)

Answer (score 1):

***Lisp recursive:***

```
(defun factorial (x) 
   (if (<= x 1) 
       1 
       (* x (factorial (- x 1)))))
```

Comment: recursive yes, but you should make it tail recursive to avoid the stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

**JavaScript**
Using anonymous functions:

```
var f = function(n){
  if(n>1){
    return arguments.callee(n-1)*n;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C: One liner, procedural

```
int f(int n) { for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; n *= i, i--); return n ? n : 1; }
```

I used int's for brevity; use other types to support larger numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, C/C++ (weave): Multi-Language, Procedural

Four implementations:

- [weave]
- [python]
- [psyco]
- [list]

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
""" weave_factorial.py

"""
# [weave] factorial() as extension module in C++
from scipy.weave import ext_tools

def build_factorial_ext():
    func = ext_tools.ext_function(
        'factorial', 
        r"""
        unsigned long long i = 1;
        for ( ; n > 1; --n)
          i *= n;

        PyObject *o = PyLong_FromUnsignedLongLong(i);
        return_val = o;
        Py_XDECREF(o); 
        """,  
        ['n'], 
        {'n': 1}, # effective type declaration
        {})
    mod = ext_tools.ext_module('factorial_ext')
    mod.add_function(func)
    mod.compile()

try: from factorial_ext import factorial as factorial_weave
except ImportError:
    build_factorial_ext()
    from factorial_ext import factorial as factorial_weave


# [python] pure python procedural factorial()
def factorial_python(n):
    i = 1
    while n > 1:
        i *= n
        n -= 1
    return i


# [psyco] factorial() psyco-optimized
try:
    import psyco
    factorial_psyco = psyco.proxy(factorial_python)
except ImportError:
    pass


# [list] list-lookup factorial()
factorials = map(factorial_python, range(21))   
factorial_list = lambda n: factorials[n]
```

---

Measure relative performance:

```
$ python -mtimeit \
         -s "from weave_factorial import factorial_$label as f" "f($n)"
```

1. n = 12

   - [weave] 0.70 µsec (**2**)
   - [python] 3.8 µsec (**9**)
   - [psyco]  1.2 µsec (**3**)
   - [list]  0.43 µsec (**1**)
2. n = 20

   - [weave] 0.85 µsec (**2**)
   - [python] 9.2 µsec (**21**)
   - [psyco]  4.3 µsec (**10**)
   - [list]  0.43 µsec (**1**)

*µsec* stands for microseconds.

Comment: It doesn't apear as if it was one file that it would run.

Comment: It would be better to post them separately anyway.

Comment: I would rather see these as a polyglot. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyglot_%28computing%29

Comment: 1. It does work as one file (how else I've got these microseconds). 2. The main function is `build_factorial_ext()`. The rest is there just for performance comparison. Therefore it would make no sense to post them separately. 3. It is *not* a polyglot. It just contains inline C++ in a Python module.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting Ruby version.  On my laptop it will find 30000! in under a second.  (It takes longer for Ruby to format it for printing than to calculate it.)  This is significantly faster than the naive solution of just multiplying the numbers in order.

```
def factorial (n)
  return multiply_range(1, n)
end

def multiply_range(n, m)
  if (m < n)
    return 1
  elsif (n == m)
    return m
  else
    i = (n + m) / 2
    return multiply_range(n, i) * multiply_range(i+1, m)
  end
end
```

Comment: This is *not* faster. What is the number of recursive calls for a given `n`? Additionally your solution is O(n) in space.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala: Recursive

- Should compile to being tail recursive. Should!

.

```
def factorial( value: BigInt ): BigInt = value match {
  case 0 => 1
  case _ => value * factorial( value - 1 )
}
```

Comment: Even in a implementation which supports tail-recursion, this wouldn't be tail recursive, because the * operation is pending after the recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

Occam-pi

```
PROC subprocess(MOBILE CHAN INT parent.out!,parent.in?)
INT value:
  SEQ
    parent.in ? value
      IF 
        value = 1
          SEQ
            parent.out ! value
        OTHERWISE
          INITIAL MOBILE CHAN INT child.in IS MOBILE CHAN INT:
          INITIAL MOBILE CHAN INT child.out IS MOBILE CHAN INT:
          FORKING
            INT newvalue:
            SEQ
              FORK subprocess(child.in!,child.out?)
              child.out ! (value-1)
              child.in ? newvalue
              parent.out ! (newalue*value)
:

PROC main(CHAN BYTE in?,src!,kyb?)
INITIAL INT value IS 0:
INITIAL MOBILE CHAN INT child.out is MOBILE CHAN INT
INITIAL MOBILE CHAN INT child.in is MOBILE CHAN INT
SEQ 
  WHILE TRUE
    SEQ
      subprocess(child.in!,child.out?)
      child.out ! value
      child.in ? value
      src ! value:
      value := value + 1
:
```

Answer (score 1):

### OCaml

Lest anyone believe OCaml and oddball go hand-in-hand, I thought I would provide a sane implementation of factorial.

```
# let rec factorial n =
    if n=0 then 1 else n * factorial(n - 1);;
```

I don't think I made my case very well...

Answer (score 1):

Genuinely functional Java:

```
public final class Factorial {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int n = Integer.valueOf(args[0]);
    System.out.println("Factorial of " + n + " is " + create(n).apply());
  }

  private static Function create(final int n) {
    return n == 0 ? new ZeroFactorialFunction() : new NFactorialFunction(n);
  }

  interface Function {
    int apply();
  }

  private static class NFactorialFunction implements Function {
    private final int n;
    public NFactorialFunction(final int n) {
      this.n = n;
    }
    @Override
    public int apply() {
      return n * Factorial.create(n - 1).apply();
    }
  }

  private static class ZeroFactorialFunction implements Function {
    @Override
    public int apply() {
      return 1;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**C# factorial using recursion in a single line**

```
private static int factorial(int n){ if (n == 0)return 1;else return n * factorial(n - 1); }
```

Answer (score 1):

## dc

Note: clobbers the `e` and `f` registers:

```
[2++d]se[d1-d_1<fd0>e*]sf
```

To use, put the value you want to take the factorial of on the top of the stack and then execute `lfx` (load the `f` register and execute it), which then pops the top of the stack and pushes that value's factorial.

Explanation: if the top of the stack is `x`, then the first part makes the top of the stack look like `(x, x-1)`.  If the new top-of-stack is non-negative, it calls factorial recursively, so now the stack is `(x, (x-1)!)` for `x` >= 1, or `(0, -1)` for `x` = 0.  Then, if the new top-of-stack is negative, it executes `2++d`, which replaces the `(0, -1)` with `(1, 1)`.  Finally, it multiplies the top two values on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](http://www.r-project.org/) - using S4 methods (recursively)

```
setGeneric( 'fct', function( x ) { standardGeneric( 'fct' ) } )
setMethod( 'fct', 'numeric', function( x ) { 
    lapply( x, function(a) { 
        if( a == 0 ) 1 else a * fact( a - 1 ) 
    } )
} )
```

Has the advantage that you can pass arrays of numbers in, and it will work them all out...

eg:

```
> fct( c( 3, 5, 6 ) )
[[1]]
[1] 6

[[2]]
[1] 120

[[3]]
[1] 720
```

Answer (score 1):

Iswim/Lucid:

`factorial = 1 fby factorial * (time+1);`

Answer (score 1):

**Python, one liner:**

A bit more clean than the other python answer.
This, and the previous answer, will fail if the input is less than 1.

def fact(n): return reduce(int.**mul**,xrange(2,n))

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp

- Call it by name: `!`
- Tail recursive
- Common Lisp handles arbitrarily large numbers

```
(defun ! (n)
  "factorial"
  (labels ((fac (n prod)
             (if (zerop n)
                 prod
                 (fac (- n 1) (* prod n)))))
    (fac n 1)))
```

*edit*:  or with accumulator as optional parameter:

```
(defun ! (n &optional prod)
  "factorial"
  (if (zerop n)
      prod
      (! (- n 1) (* prod n))))
```

or as a reduce, at the cost of a bigger memory footprint and more consing:

```
(defun range (start end &optional acc)
  "range from start inclusive to end exclusive, start = start end)
      (nreverse acc)
      (range (+ start 1) end (cons start acc))))

(defun ! (n)
  "factorial"
  (reduce #'* (range 1 (+ n 1))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Factor

USE: math.ranges

: factorial ( n -- n! ) 1 [a,b] product ;

Answer (score 1):

In MUMPS:

```
fact(N)
  N F,I S F=1 F  I=2:1:N S F=F*I
  QUIT F
```

Or, if you're a fan of indirection:

```
fact(N)
  N F,I S F=1 F I=2:1:N S F=F_"*"_I
  QUIT @F
```

Answer (score 1):

**ActionScript: Procedural/OOP**

```
function f(n) {
    var result = n>1 ? arguments.callee(n-1)*n : 1;
    return result;
}
// function call
f(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... no TCL

```
proc factorial {n} {
  if { $n == 0 } { return 1 }
  return [expr {$n*[factorial [expr {$n-1}]]}]
}
puts [factorial 6]
```

But of course that doesn't work for a damn for large values of n.... we can do better with tcllib!

```
package require math::bignum
proc factorial {n} {
  if { $n == 0 } { return 1 }
  return [ ::math::bignum::tostr [ ::math::bignum::mul [
    ::math::bignum::fromstr $n] [ ::math::bignum::fromstr [
      factorial [expr {$n-1} ]
    ]]]]
}
puts [factorial 60]
```

Look at all those ]'s at the end.  This is practically LISP!

I'll leave the version for values of n>2^32 as an excersize for the reader

Comment: Hmm... aren't these all examples of reasons NOT to use TCL?  I'm converting to and from strings on each iteration.  Is there a way to do this with tail-calls?  does TCL have Tail Calls?(I cannot answer that last one)

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, Memoized

```
f[n_ /; n < 2] := 1
f[n_] := (f[n] = n*f[n - 1])
```

Mathematica supports n! natively, but this shows how to make definitions on the fly.  When you execute f[2], this code will make a definition f[2]=2 which will subsequently be executed no differently than if you'd hard-coded it; no need for an internal data structure; you just use the language's own function definition machinery.

Answer (score 1):

**Lisp : tail-recursive**

```
(defun factorial(x)
  (labels((f (x acc)
             (if (> x 1)
                 (f (1- x)(* x acc))
                 acc)))
         (f x 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another ruby one.

```
class Integer
  def fact
    return 1 if self.zero?
    (1..self).to_a.inject(:*)
  end
end
```

This works if to_proc is supported on symbols.

Answer (score 1):

## REBOL

Math is *definitely* not one of REBOL's strong points, since it lacks arbitrary precision integers. For the sake of completeness, I thought I'd add it anyway.

Here's a standard, naïve recursive implementation:

```
fac: func [ [catch] n [integer!] ] [
    if n < 0 [ throw make error! "Hey dummy, your argument was less than 0!" ]
    either n = 0 [ 1 ] [
        n * fac (n - 1)
    ]
]
```

And that's about it. Move along, folks, nothing to see here ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's my proposal. Runs in Mathematica, works fine:

```
gen[f_, n_] := Module[{id = -1, val = Table[Null, {n}], visit},
  visit[k_] := Module[{t},
    id++; If[k != 0, val[[k]] = id];
    If[id == n, f[val]];
    Do[If[val[[t]] == Null, visit[t]], {t, 1, n}];
    id--; val[[k]] = Null;];
  visit[0];
  ]

Factorial[n_] := Module[{res=0}, gen[res++&, n]; res]
```

**Update**
Ok, here's how it works: the visit function is from Sedgewick's Algorithm book, it "visits" all permutations of length n. Upon the visit, it calls function f with the permutation as an argument.

So, Factorial enumerates all permutations of length n, and for each permutation the counter res is increased, thus computing n! in O(n+1)! time.

Comment: I wonder how this works. It seems it counts all possible permutations of length n, amirite?

Comment: Yes exactly! And now I'm beyond the 15 character limit.

Answer (score 1):

Python:

```
def factorial(n):
    return reduce(lambda x, y: x * y,range(1, n + 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP - 59 chars

```
function f($n){return array_reduce(range(1,$n),'bcmul',1);}
```

---

## Improved Version - 27 chars

```
array_product(range(1,$n));
```

Answer (score 1):

### SETL

...where Haskell and Python borrowed their list comprehensions from.

```
proc factorial(n);
    return 1 */ {1..n};
end factorial;
```

And the built-in `INTEGER` type is arbitrary-precision, so this will work for any positive `n`.

Answer (score 1):

[## Befunge:](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge)

```
0&>:1-:v v *_$.@ 
  ^    _$>\:^
```

Answer (score 1):

### CLOS

I see Common Lisp solutions abusing recursion, LOOP, and even FORMAT.  I guess it's time for somebody to write a solution that abuses CLOS!

```
(defgeneric factorial (n))
(defmethod factorial ((n (eql 0))) 1)
(defmethod factorial ((n integer)) (* n (factorial (1- n))))
```

(Can your favorite language's object system dispatcher do that?)

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript: designed for golfing, of course

```
~),1>{*}*
```

- `~` evaluates the input string (to an integer)
- `)` increments the number
- `,` is range (4, becomes [0 1 2 3])
- `1>` selects values whose index is 1 or bigger
- `{*}*` folds multiplication over the list
- Stack contents are printed when the program terminates.

To run:

```
echo 5 | ruby gs.rb fact.gs
```

Answer (score 1):

### Oh fork() its another example in Perl

This will make use of your multiple core CPUs... although perhaps not in the most effective manner.  The *open* statement clones the process with fork and opens a pipe from the child process to the parent. The work of multiplying numbers 2 at a time is split among a tree of very short lived processes. Of course, this example is a bit silly. The point is that if you actually had more difficult calculations to do then this example illustrates one way to divide up the work in parallel.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use bigint;

print STDOUT &main::rangeProduct(1,$ARGV[0])."\n";

sub main::rangeProduct {
    my($l, $h) = @_;
    return $l    if ($l==$h);
    return $l*$h if ($l==($h-1));
    # arghhh - multiplying more than 2 numbers at a time is too much work
    # find the midpoint and split the work up :-)
    my $m = int(($h+$l)/2);
    my $pid = open(my $KID, "-|");
      if ($pid){ # parent
        my $X = &main::rangeProduct($l,$m);
        my $Y = <$KID>;
        chomp($Y);
        close($KID);
        die "kid failed" unless defined $Y;
        return $X*$Y;
      } else {
        # kid
        print STDOUT &main::rangeProduct($m+1,$h)."\n";
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL: Recursive CTE

Inline table function using a recursive common table expression. SQL Server 2005 and up.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Factorial(@n int) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    WITH RecursiveCTE (N, Value) AS
    (
        SELECT 1, CAST(1 AS decimal(38,0))
        UNION ALL
        SELECT N+1, CAST(Value*(N+1) AS decimal(38,0))
        FROM RecursiveCTE
    )
    SELECT TOP 1 Value
    FROM RecursiveCTE
    WHERE N = @n
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell : Functional - Tail Recursive

```
factorial n = factorial' n 1

factorial' 0 a = a
factorial' n a = factorial' (n-1) (n*a)
```

Answer (score 0):

**FoxPro:**

```
function factorial
    parameters n
return iif( n>0, n*factorial(n-1), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp, since noone has commited that yet:

```
(defun factorial (n)
  (if (<= n 1)
      1 
      (* n (factorial (1- n)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Common Lisp

I'm fairly sure this could be more effieicnet. It is my first lisp function other than "hello, world" and typing in the example code in the third chapter. *Practical Common Lisp* is a great text. This function does seem to handle large factorials well.

```
(defun factorial (x)
  (if (< x 2) (return-from factorial (print 1)))
  (let ((tempx 1) (ans 1))
  (loop until (equalp x tempx) do
       (incf tempx)
       (setf ans (* tempx ans)))
  (list ans)))
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Io](http://iolanguage.org/):

```
factorial := method(n,
    if (list(0, 1) contains(n),
       1,
       n * factorial(n - 1)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

C++ constexpr

```
constexpr uint64_t fact(uint32_t n)
{
    return  (n==0) ? 1:n*fact(n-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vb6 :**

```
Private Function factCalculation(ByVal Number%)
  Dim intNum%
  intNum = 1
  For i = 2 To Number
     intNum = intNum * Number
  Next i
  return intNum
End Function

Private Sub Form_Load()
 Dim FactResult% : FactResult = factCalculation(3) 'e.g
 Print FactResult
End Sub
```